# Configuring Jackson XmlMapper for my requirements

Tags: xml, jackson, marshalling

I want to configure jackson XmlMapper so that writeValueAsString method will  provide following requirements:

```
1. Eliminate null/empty tags: Ex: <carrierDocumentId/>
2. Tags to display its namespace: Ex: <documentId> to displayed as   
  <ims:documentId>
3. Tags to use the upper case letter as provided in 
     @XmlElement(name = "DocumentId")
4. List objects to not to include a wrapper tag: 
<documentId><documentId>12345</documentId></documentId>
5. Attribute tags to display as attribute instead of element: 
  Ex: <id><value>6802554587</value><idOrigin>Invoice</idOrigin></id>
  to be displayed as <id  idOrigin="Invoice">6802554587</id>
```

I tried with different combinations:

```
   //JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        //AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new 
        JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(serializeMapper.getTypeFactory());   
        //serializeMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        //serializeMapper.registerModule(module);       

     //serializeMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE,false);      

   //serializeMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

   //serializeMapper.enable(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME);

   //serializeMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        //JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        // and then configure, for example:
        //module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
        serializeMapper = new XmlMapper();  
        AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new 
         JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(serializeMapper.getTypeFactory());   
        serializeMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
        serializeMapper.registerModule(module);
```

thanks
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

I used JAXB classes as follows and removed the jackson XmlMapper.
       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ShowInvoice.class);
       Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
This provided the formating I was looking for

Thanks
Madhu